# No suitable driver found for jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc

I took this example from Oracle's website and I am not able to implement it. It keeps on showing an error. I have already added the mysql 5.1 driver jar to my projects lib folder 
and also to my build path. How do I fix my code ?

link - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

error -

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:JavaEE://localHost:3306/
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at com.beans.us.dao.Data.getConnection(Data.java:25)
    at com.beans.us.dao.Data.main(Data.java:43)
Cannot connect to database
```

code -

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Data {

    public static Connection getConnection() {

        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "root";
        String dbms = "JavaEE";
        String serverName = "localHost";
        String portNumber = "3306";

        connectionProps.put("user", userName);
        connectionProps.put("password", password);

        try {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + dbms + "://"
                    + serverName + ":" + portNumber + "/", connectionProps);
        } catch (SQLException sQLException) {
            sQLException.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to database");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cannot connect to database");
        }

        return conn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        getConnection();

    }

}
```

Comment: what kind of JavaEE database? I haven't seen, the default db with java friends is derby

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your connection string is:

```
"jdbc:JavaEE://..."
```

but with MySQL it should be

```
"jdbc:mysql://..."
```

Also, your forgot to load the driver:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

It needs to be done before calling

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
```

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); is not needed here. Your answer wins. I thought that the dbms meant my db. Dumb error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have forgotten to load the driver .

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

The `Class.forName()` causes the ClassLoader to load the class into memory. JDBC driver classes contain a static initializer block that registers the driver with `DriverManager` for later reference.

Didn't notice this earlier , your connection string should be `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"`

Comment: version 4 jdbc drivers no longer need that.

Comment: @jtahlborn - yeah. I had that line in my code and it still failed. So I removed the line before posting the code on SO. Downvoted the answer. I recommend that the answer be downvoted to 0 points and no further.

Answer (score 0):

Your jdbc string is not properly formatted, take a look at the answers of this question:

[What is the MySQL JDBC driver connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457716/what-is-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-connection-string)