# Database Access Denied connection issue

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to make mysql database connection from my war file using jdbc  connection  string as shown below:-

```
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseName? user=DatabaseUserName;password=DatabasePassword";
```

Now my war file and database both available on server, & i am doing my execution from server itself. But the problem is that i am getting below error which  says:-

```
    INFO: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'grandsho_root;password=pwd'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

where

grandsho_root is my user, pwd is my password  ...I need to know what exactly is this problem? Do i need to perform GRANT ALL command.  or something like that?

Comment: Try to grant all privileges to user grandsho_root. Should work.

Comment: @user2339071 i have done that?

Comment: It's not a GRANT issue. The user credentials are not known. There are 3 parts to the credentials: username, password, hostname. Make sure there is actually a user called grand_sho with your password that is allowed to connect from localhost.

Comment: have a look here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457716/what-is-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-connection-string

Comment: @Xabster is my connection string correct which is mentioned in my question? i have created user for that database, but as you said make sure user with password allowed to connect? how to do this step on my server?

Comment: please use DriverManager.getConnection(String url, String user, String password) instead of DriverManager.getConnection(String url)

Comment: @user2656285: no, there's indeed something wrong with how you're trying it. The error says that it did not receive a password. Use DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password) like the guy above said.

Comment: @shola thanks i've tried this earlier, but will try again now

Answer (score 0):

When you get the message "(using password: NO)" this means you were trying to connect without a password set. The log message tells you that the user "grandsho_root;password=pwd" is not allowed to connect. This means your connection string is wrong because you use ; to separate your parameters instead of a &. This is how your connection string should look:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseName?user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw
```

When you still have problems please check if your user is set up correctly. Check that grandsho_root has a password set, that he is allowed to connect from localhost and you granted the necessary privileges to your schema.

Also check the MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html)

Comment: how to make sure that my user is allowed to connect from  localhost?

Comment: via command line you can check which host is allowed for your user with: "use mysql; select user, host from user;" You can add entries the users table or update it as you want. But be sure to fire a "flush privileges;" afterwards.