# Java Database connectivity on GNU/Linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux, odbc, unixodbc

I'm having a Java class and I'm really new to Database Connectivity.. My professor and everyone else on this class use Windows and an Access Database, and I'm the only one using `GNU/Linux` with a `MYSQL Database`. 
Now as you know Windows programmers use `ODBC`, but as I searched, I got that it's only for windows. I found a `Unix/Linux ODBC` from easysoft but it doesn't support `MYSQL`
Is there any Open-Source `ODBC` you know of that supports MYSQL?
Moreover how should I use this Driver in java?
 Couldn't find neither a documentation nor a tutorial for GNU/Linux..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just install MySQL Connectors  from this** [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

**Code to connect to mysql via jdbc :**

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?" + "user=test&password=123456");
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }                                             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides both ODBC and JDBC drivers. Check their web site. Documentation is also provided.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about ODBC drivers. You just need the MySQL JDBC driver.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Here is also some info on setting up the connection:

[What is the MySQL JDBC driver connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457716/what-is-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-connection-string)