# Driver not found: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] no matter what i do

Tags: java, playframework

I'm totally new to play and trying to add managed MySQL dependency in java play `2.3.6`.

**build.sbt:**

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.21"
```

**application.conf**

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="mysql://user:pass@localhost:81/play"
```

And i get `[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]` .

What am i missing?

Comment: `jdbc:localhost:81/play` does not look like a valid JDBC URL for MySQL. What this URL looks like, depends on the database. Lookup the syntax for the JDBC URL for MySQL and correct it. See [What is the MySQL JDBC driver connection string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457716/what-is-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-connection-string)

Comment: Did you do a `clean` and `dependencies` before trying to compile and run it again? (I have missed that myself some times...)

Comment: @Jesper - i followed your advice and fixed the url according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457716/what-is-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-connection-string . But now after clean / run it's stuck on `Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources` for the past 8m . Is it supposed to do this?

Comment: @Jesper - finished it, but didn't solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, in case anyone stumbles upon similar problem:

running `clean` isn't enough, running `reload` after inserting the dependency solved it for me. (I don't know how is this in older versions, but that is how it is in `2.3.6`

Comment: Changes to your build file are not automatically picked up by an existing sbt session without a `reload`.  `clean` only impacts artifacts from your project, not the project build itself.

Comment: Just what i said , `clean` isn't enough and `reload` is needed, if you want you can post comprehensive answer and i'll accept in case anyone will find this page with similar problem.