# Connection string for MySQL with multiple connection parameters?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In reference to this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457716/what-is-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-connection-string), I'm trying to frame the connection string to connect to MySQL database with the following connection parameters, but I'm unable to get it right.

I've referred the [**documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) that the post is referring to, but I'm unable to resolve even after following the instructions. Can anybody help me in this regard?

Connection Parameters that are being used:

- `useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true`
- `useUnicode=true`
- `characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Normal connection string: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/databaseName`

Adding these connection parameters and their corresponding values, how would the connection string be?

Comment: Usecase that I work, adds or drops the connection parameters - Hence I have to change the connection string based on the need!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [reference documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), it would be:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/databaseName?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&unicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

However, the standard port is 3306 not 3307 like in your question.

Comment: You've got a valid point!, whereas I have two versions of MySQL installed, hence used 2 ports for these!

Comment: Just thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Arthur Noseda, your comment definitely helps others! Cheers!

Answer (score 12):

Just stitch parameters like a url, eg:

```
jdbc:MySql://localhost:3307/databaseName?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true&useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true
```

If your connection string is being held in an XML or properties document, you need to encode `&` as `&amp;`, like this:

```
jdbc:MySql://localhost:3307/databaseName?characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true
```

Comment: You need to encode this *if* the connection string is being held in an XML document. Not otherwise. There is nothing about XML in the question.

Comment: Also `jdbc:MySql:` is not the prefix of the MySQL driver, that is `jdbc:mysql:`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  jdbc:mysql: can be written in uppercase. it doesn't matter

Comment: @EJP Yes, you're right. But in my work, I always adhere to do that even the connection string is not being held in an XML or properties document, which is still not wrong.