# How to access database through wireless lan

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am using Netbeans IDE and Java and jdbc to connect to Oracle database locally (that is the database and the program are stored on same computer)

But I wanna access the database through program which is stored on different computer.

How to do that as well as what extra software is needed and what should be the URL for `DriverManager.getConnection()`

My current `DriverManager.getConnection` is something like this....

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",condb.usrnm,condb.psswrd);
```

Comment: Assuming you have the same database technology, then just replace `localhost:1521` with the address of the server.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457716/what-is-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-connection-string 
your localhost should point to the hostname of the computer where database is ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `localhost` into the hostname or the ip address of your db server. In the example below I have changed into `server.remote.net`.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.remote.net:1521:XE",condb.usrnm,condb.psswrd);
```

Then pay attention to the port, I assume that your server is listening on port `1521`. Because 1521 is Oracle server the standard port.

After that you have to be sure that there is network connection to your server. There are many ways to do it. As suggested by @YCF_L you could ping the server:

```
ping server.remote.net
```

or telnet

```
telnet server.remote.net 1521
```

Another important thing you have to pay attention is the `XE` keyword in the jdbc connection string. Which is the Oracle instance name. Your remote server can have an Oracle Instance named differently `COMPANY_DATA`

This means that your connection string could change into:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.remote.net:1521:COMPANY_DATA",condb.usrnm,condb.psswrd);
```

On the other hand, on the remote computer there could be a different Database Engine. Like MySql, MS SQL Server, Postgres, etc. In this case the jdbc connection string changes much more.

Answer (score 0):

You should to specify the right IP address of the target computer :

```
Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipOfTargetPc:1521:XE", condb.usrnm, condb.psswrd);
```

You can ping in the target computer and get the IP address.

Comment: That's it just change to IP address no additional software or a setups

Comment: nope, just the ip address and the correct port number and make sure that there are a connection between the two computers